# Внесение в базу данных с полей input у которых одинаковый name

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, строки

Привожу пример, у меня есть кнопка Добавить которая добавляет новое поле для ввода текста input type="text" у всех них естественно один и тот же name дабы я мог отследить данные которые в них находятся

Что требуется - брать информацию со всех строк которые были созданы и вносить их в базу в одну таблицу

вот скрин того как выглядят поля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у всех них одинаковый name ->

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне их внести в базу данных? желательно чтобы я мог потом отследить какая это была серия, первая строка - первая серия, вторая строка - вторая серия. и т.д

вот пытался что-то реализовать но ничего не выходит ->

```
$links = $_POST['player-link'];
$sn = 0;
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $sn + 1;
    mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "INSERT INTO `player-hent` (`tid`, `sn`, `player-link`) VALUES ($getter[id], $sn, $link)");
}
```

переменная sn это что-то типа моего обозначения серии.

tid это айди сериала к которому относятся эти серии. с ним проблем нет там все ясно

делал что-то подобное но с жанрами. вот как оно записывалось в базе ->

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

tid = идентификатор сериала
jid = идентификатор жанра

как вы видите некоторые жанры(jid) привязаны к одному сериалу(tid)
что и позволяет мне выводить их в нужном сериале. хочу сделать тоже самое но вместо jid будут ссылки на серии

если есть свои варианты которые будут выполнять туже функцию, готов послушать.

Comment: сделать не `name="x"`а `name="x[]"`

Comment: он у меня так и записан во втором скрине

Comment: что конкретно не выходит то? зы: 1) код приводите текстом 2: `$sn + 1` не меняет значение в цикле 3) для передаче параметров в запрос используйте подготовленные выражения. 4) формируйте один запрос на вставку нескольких строк сразу.

Comment: к слову просто, данный код не рабочий в моем случае ->     $links = $_POST['player-link'];
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "INSERT INTO `player-hent` (`tid`, `player-link`) VALUES ($getter[id], $link)");
    }

Comment: я формирую один запрос циклом, дабы оно разбивало каждое поле в базе на свои определенные строки и не заносило все в одну строку

Comment: в данный момент оно не вносит в таблицу вообще ничего

Comment: вы формируете свой запрос на каждую  строку. я же пишу про запись `insert into.. values (row1), (row2), (row3)` которая вставляет все строки одним запросом

Comment: Включите отображение ошибок и нотисов пхп,  проверьте результат выполнения запроса обработайте вывод ошибок mysql. Без этого вы можете долго писать "оно просто не работает", хотя надо всего лишь взять информацию и прочитать, что конкретно не работает.

Comment: оно же в базу данных вносит все в одну строку, разве нет?

Comment: и учебник по sql тоже почитайте

Comment: не получается разбить строки. мне нужно чтобы каждая серия в таблице имела свою строку с привязанным к ней идентификатором серии. в данный момент строки с одинаковым name[] попросту не разбиваются и не вносятся в базу по отдельности как мне и надо. я не хочу пихать все ссылки на серии в одну строку. мне нужно разбить их чтобы они лежали в одной таблице отдельно друг от друга имея один общий идентификатор который привязывает их к сериалу.

Comment: после чего я буду методом while вытаскивать каждую ссылку из таблицы и вставлять их в раздел с просмотром сериала.

Comment: @teran все твои рекомендации по делу, кроме того что ты уперся в ненужное "пихай в одну строку". Мало того что это "при использовании подготовленных выражений" превращается в нетривиальную для новичка задачу и само по себе отвлекает автора от решения реальных проблем, но главное само по себе абсолютно бессмысленно, никакой пользы не несет

Comment: @Ипатьев да почему же уперся? хочет так пусть циклом вставляет, если выражение подготовит. Если у него там 3 серии вставляется, то мб выгоды и не несет, да, хуже правда тоже не сделает. меня тут больше беспокоит, что он там циклом while решил их вытаскивать потом по одной.

Comment: @teran ну а как еще-то? вообще это тоже мелочь, как хочет, пусть так и вытаскивает

Comment: @Ипатьев ага, а потом в следующем вопросе напишешь ему "Здесь неверно вообще все" :)

Comment: спасибо за дискуссию но мне что делать то

Comment: о выводе я вообще не беспокоюсь там пройдет все гладко. если я смогу внести в базу все в том виде как я хочу

Comment: я уже делал что-то подобное но там был элемент select с множественной выборкой

Comment: и я спокойно вносил их в базу и потом выводил это в нужном сериале

Comment: я обновил пост. посмотрите мб как-то смог объяснить чего хочу добиться

Comment: @Ипатьев ну что как там

Answer (score 0):

проблема в том как ты пишешь переменные в запрос. Это **никогда** нельзя делать напрямую. Переменные надо в сегда передавать отдельно

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `player-hent` (`tid`, `sn`, `player-link`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $CONNECTDB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$getter['id'], $sn, $link);

foreach ($_POST['player-link'] as $sn => $link) {
    $sn++;
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: нельзя. кавычек СОВСЕМ недостаточно. Учите пожалуйста синтаксис SQL. И если у вас есть по нему вопросы, то их следует задавать в форме вопроса, а не в виде комментария к чужому ответу

Comment: @user413219 извините, но вы не поняли ни вопроса, который был здесь задан, ни ответа, ни моего комментария. Очень прошу, если у вас есть какие-то вопросы по синтаксису SQL или PHP, то задавать их в форме вопроса. Спасибо.